# Android: Get 'title' from url without fetching the entire page

Tags: android, parsing, url, dom, web

I want to fetch titles of many urls in my Android app. 
I found one way of doing it using [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get(); // Fetches the HTML document
String title = doc.title(); // Parses the HTML document
```

But the problem with this is, the `get()` method fetches the entire HTML document and parses the the title from it. Now that I have too many urls to parse in my app, this makes my app use a lot of internet just to get the title from the url.

The other way I could think of is creating a web service, my app makes a request to this web service with the url, the web service fetches the entire HTML doc from the url and it returns just the title to the app. But I have no experience with web services and hence is difficult for me.

Is it possible to get **just the title** of url without using web services? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you can't, I mean I don't think you can specify a thing like this in an HTTP request. But you could prepare a file with a sort of server machine containing only titles and with Android downloading directly that file

Comment: My app contains URLs from third party, hence are dynamic. @firegloves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No, it is not possible to download only a part of an HTML page. HTTP has no method for partial download. There's only HTTP HEAD for getting the HTTP headers and HTTP GET which fully downloads a resource.

The only thing you can save on is the parsing. By not parsing the whole DOM, but only parsing the single elements, e.g. using the SAX API, you can stop the parsing at the end of the title.

Answer (score -1):

u can use WebView and the get web title
Or

u can use split  function